# Introduce something to something

Tags: sentence

"CleverIS User Interface Changer quickly introduces legacy applications to the latest trends, such as mobile and web technologies."

I'm not sure about the meaning of the word "introduces" in this sentence. Does it mean to "insert" or to "present"? Or maybe something else...Is it that the "legacy applications" become available quickly?? on the "latest trends/technologies"?Could anyone help me on this?Thank You!

Comment: It is figurative language, saying that legacy applications are outdated because they do not incorporate the newest trends. So they will become updated if they are "introduced" to the latest trends, like two people who don't know each other.

Comment: But it should be the other way around.  CleverIS quickly. Introduces the latest trends in mobile and web technology to legacy applications.  And then it means *insert*.

Comment: @Jim: if you switch the order, as you've done, then yes it does mean *insert* - although it should probably use "into" instead of "in". However, that's **not** what this sentence appears to intend. As jlovegren correctly explains, "introduces" is deliberately used metaphorically. It paints an anthropomorphic picture of CleverIS saying to a legacy application, "Hello, my dear old thing. I'd like you to meet my very modern friends, Mobile Tech and Web Tech. I think they can help you."

Comment: @Chappo - two things. 1. I meant “latest trends **in** web technologies” so ***in*** is correct. 2. My point was that using “introduces” in the sense you suggest is not idiomatic here so I was trying to fix it.

Comment: As an IT person, I read that as - allows to use/opens up to use...CleverIS UI Changer quickly allows legacy applications to make use of the latest trends, such as mobile and web technologies.

Comment: Interestingly, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compatibilized) has: **compatibilized**

simple past tense and past participle of _compatibilize_ but has deleted its 'compatibilize' page.